# VSCode (TSC and Python) tasks

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up two different tasks (a python script which essentially copies source to destination) and then the actual build task which concat the TSC files to a single JS file, in Visual Studio Code's Configure Task Runner:

My code looks as below:

```
 {
        // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
        // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
        "version": "0.1.0",
        "command": "bash",
        "isShellCommand": true,
        "showOutput": "always",
        "args": [
            "-c"
        ],
        "tasks": [
            {
                "taskName": "python",
                "isBuildCommand": false,
                "args": ["/usr/bin/python includeAsset.py"]
            },
            {
                "taskName": "build",
                "isBuildCommand": true,
                "args": ["-p", ".", "--outFile", "bin/js/main.js"],
                "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am unable to figure out what the problem is. This is my first attempt at VSCode and am completely clueless as to what I'm doing wrong. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What's the error message that's being displayed.

Comment: Thanks for you're response:

`-p: build: command not found`

This is the error, which is basically the second taskName.